# AVA test setup: "Unexpected token export"

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ava

## Problem

I'm trying to add AVA tests to a project and my tests are not parsing ES2015 modules correctly with my Babel setup. What is odd to me is the `import`s are working fine and if I run my `npm run build` and run the output from the REPL it works...so it seems that AVA is not transpiling `export` statements correctly or something is wrong with my config in my `package.json`? I've tried reading through the docs and looking at other examples without success.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Clone https://github.com/trevordmiller/utility-functions
2. `checkout` the `tests` branch
3. `npm install`
4. `npm test`

Get an error (screenshot below) - ES2015 module `export` error on line 7 of `getURLSlug`:

[image: AVA test error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "require": ["babel-register"] to the AVA configuration in your package.json

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Kent 

Comment: This didn't work for me. Probably due to the complexity in my application.

Comment: This should now be `npm i -D @babel/register` and `"require": ["@babel/register"]` for babel 7. Also see [the ava docs about this](https://github.com/avajs/babel/blob/v1.0.1/README.md).